# c++ Hex Array appends characters

Tags: c++

I have a char array storing hex

```
char peer0_0[]  = {0xc1, 0x02, 0x06, 0x08, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x84};
```

I try and read the value in a log

```
std::stringstream ss2;
ss2 << std::hex;
for (int i(0) ; i<8 ; ++i)
    ss2 << (int)peer0_0[i] << ' ';
m_manager->log(ss2.str(),HIGH_IMPORTANCE);
```

The result is

```
ffffffc1 2 6 8 0 5e ffffff84 0
```

I don't understand why it appends 'ffffff' before only two values and not others? Also why is there a zero in the end? Is this a problem of reading? Please help.

Comment: `char` is signed on your platform, you'll need to cast it to `unsigned char` before `int`.

Comment: The zero (or other garbage) on the end is because you loop while `i<8` but there are only seven elements. Change `8` to `7` or `sizeof peer0_0`. Or use a range-based loop.

Comment: I'd say, use printf, the std:: stuf sucks.

Comment: @V-X: You'd need `s(n)printf`, not `printf`, plus a pile of nasty memory-management code, to write the numbers into a string; `stringstream` arguably sucks less than that. And it won't solve this problem, since each `char` will still be converted to `int` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `f`s come because you cast to `int` and those two numbers had their top bit set, i.e. they are negative numbers and "sign extended" to make 32-bit integers.

The `0` on the end is actually undefined behavior: you are printing 8 numbers in your loop, but only have 7 in your array.

Comment: How can I convert unsigned char array to char array? I need to pass this array to socket send()

Comment: I get an error when I do this

unsigned char *arr = {0xc1, 0x02, 0x06, 0x08, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x84};

Comment: I need to pass this array to socket send() which takes a const char * so either I have to convert the unsigned char array to const char *

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your compiler by default considers type `char` as `signed char`. In this case for example value

```
0xc1
```

is considered as negative number because the sign bit is set.

You could define your array as

```
unsigned char peer0_0[]  = {0xc1, 0x02, 0x06, 0x08, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x84};
```

Or you could explicitly cast each element of the array to type `unsigned char`

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < sizeof( peer0_0 ) ; ++i )
    ss2 << (int)static_cast<unsigned char>( peer0_0[i] ) << ' ';
```

Take into account that your array has only 7 elements.

Comment: `char` and `signed char` are distinct types, regardless of whether or not the OP's compiler treats `char` as a signed type.

Comment: Now the problem is to convert unsigned char to const char *

Comment: @user2837961 You are not initializing an array but a single object. Write instead unsigned char arr[] = {0xc1, 0x02, 0x06, 0x08, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x84};

Answer (score 0):

You can use the std::setw function to limit the size of the printed numbers.

```
std::stringstream ss2;
ss2 << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    ss2 << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(peer0_0[i]) << ' ';
}
std::cout << ss2.str() << std::endl;
```